# javascript conditional logic not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

When I try to run the code below, and step into it in the browser debugger, the length it's showing me is 1 or higher, yet it still drops into this block as if it were evaluated as true...am I missing something here?

```
  function checkEmpty() {
            var empty = false;
            $('form input:text').each(function () {
                console.log($(this).val())
                if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
                    empty = true;
                }
            });

            if (empty) {
                $('#btnContinueCheckout1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#btnContinueCheckout2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                $('#btnContinueCheckout1').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#btnContinueCheckout2').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        }
```

HTML: (these are the input fields, and they are wrapped around a form, and have 2 checkout buttons that are not shown)

```
  <br />
    <br />
    <label><strong>Full Name: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </strong></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" required="required" onkeyup="checkEmpty()" name="FullName" style="width: 235px;" /><br />
    <br />
    <label><strong>Mailing Address: &nbsp;</strong></label>
    <input type="text" required="required" name="Address" onkeyup="checkEmpty()" style="width: 235px;" /><br />
    <br />
    <label><strong>Email: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</strong></label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" required="required" style="width: 235px;" name="Email" onkeyup="checkEmpty()" /><br />
    <br />
    <label><strong>Phone Number: </strong></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" required="required" name="Phone" onkeyup="checkEmpty()" />
```

Comment: you have set debugger on if statement line?

Comment: No, it's a fairly basic `if()` statement.  Maybe try logging the length before and after the block to ensure it did/ didn't get ran?

Comment: Do a `console.log($(this).val())` and post the output. :-)

Comment: Can you show some more code?

Comment: Post also the HTML code.

Comment: Okay, and how do I show the log? It's my first time using that feature.

Comment: @user3267755 Press F12, and go to Console. Otherwise, you can use `alert($(this).val())` if it's easier

Comment: Could it be that he forgot the `;` at the end of `console.log($(this).val());` ?

Comment: No, it seems that one of the textfields has length 0.

Comment: Okay, so in the console.log, every keyup in one of the 4 textboxes I do, it pops up an alert that says undefined.

Comment: On which line does it give you the undefined alert? You may be pointing to an object that doesn't exist on the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example code in a blank html page with jQuery linked:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label><strong>Full Name: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </strong></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="text" required="required" onkeyup="checkEmpty()" name="FullName" style="width: 235px;" /><br />
        <br />
        <label><strong>Mailing Address: &nbsp;</strong></label>
        <input type="text" required="required" name="Address" onkeyup="checkEmpty()" style="width: 235px;" /><br />
        <br />
        <label><strong>Email: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</strong></label>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" required="required" style="width: 235px;" name="Email" onkeyup="checkEmpty()" /><br />
        <br />
        <label><strong>Phone Number: </strong></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="text" required="required" name="Phone" onkeyup="checkEmpty()" />
        <input type="button" id="checkbutton" value="deactivated" disabled/>
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkEmpty() {
    var empty = false;
    $('form input:text').each(function () {
        console.log($(this).val());
        if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
       $('#checkbutton').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#checkbutton').prop('disabled', '');
    }

    console.log('count of textfields: ' + $('form input:text').length);
}
</script>
</html>
```

It works 100% for me. Look at the console to check the count for the textfields. If it's more then you expect, check your html if you have missed one. If all fields are filled, the button will be activated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're assigning `empty=true;` when you read one input field, but then the loop will keep going and check further input fields. This means that if the first field is empty, but the second one isn't empty, your loop will not work. Try to break out of the .each() loop as soon as you find the first empty input.

```
function checkEmpty() {
        var empty = false;
        $('form input:text').each(function () {
            console.log($(this).val()); // Also, you forgot the ; here
            if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
                empty = true;
                return false; // Will break out of the .each() loop
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#btnContinueCheckout1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#btnContinueCheckout2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#btnContinueCheckout1').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#btnContinueCheckout2').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
```

Comment: He don't need to break out (it's better ofc) but that doesn't cause his problem.